# Como puedo cambiar el contraste de la pantalla en Windows 11

Tags: windows, motor-de-juego, screen

Tengo el problema en Windows 11, estaba dentro de un juego y al cerrar, noté que la pantalla quedó con mucho brillo y sobre todo en el texto se ve como si no tuviese contraste. He intentado cambiar los temas, el tema de contraste, el brillo y reiniciando. Agregando, todo esto con la configuración de brillo de Windows en 0%

Comment: Recuerda que [es.so] es un sitio de preguntas acerca de _programación_.

Answer (score 0):

RESUELTO.
No estaba editando las configuraciones de la tarjeta gráfica, en mi caso AMD RADEON GRAPHICS, Click derecho en escritorio, AMD Radeon y restablecer valores